# CakePHP 2.3 loads model classes in production but not in test environment "case sensitive cause"

Tags: php, linux, apache, cakephp, case-sensitive

I have an environment that uses CakePHP 1.3 and 2.3, both are using the same model classes.

My reusable models path is: /var/www/libs/cakephp/models/*

In my config/bootstrap.php file i have set:

```
App::build(array(
    'Model' => array('/var/www/libs/cakephp/models/'),
));
```

In production environment everything works perfectly fine, but at testing environment the classes inside 'models/*' folder are not loading.

Both servers are LAMP.

After a lot of trial and error i discovered that if I rename my files inside models/ at **testing** environment folder from **m**yclassname.php to **M**yclassname.php everything works fine!

So the problem is with the Case in the name files.

I know the conventions of CakePHP 2.3, that model classes should be CamelCase, but those classes are needed in old CakePHP 1.3 apps. The question here is about difference between configs when using same version of Framework, PHP and linux.

What could be the cause of my problem?

In development environment (Windows) everything works fine too.

Comment: You might get some useful info with e.g. `debug(get_included_files());`. Clearly there's something different between the setup of the production and testing environments - you can avoid problems by for example: `cd /var/www/libs/cakephp/models/; ln -s myclassname.php MyClassname.php` - i.e. make each model available in both cases (though, sharing files like this between different major versions is a bad idea - use a seperate checkout/copy of your shared models for each version).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by AD7six I have created symbolic links to my models allowing CakePHP 1.3 and 2.3 to request the classes files independently from case.

```
cd /var/www/libs/cakephp/models/; ln -s myclassname.php MyClassname.php
```